# Time Difference Exists Between the Client and the Server

Tags: php, javascript

Javascript:

```
function setinvitexpire(){

var ee = new Date ();
ee.setTime(ee.getTime() + (365 * 24 * 3600 * 1000));

var bb = Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000) + (24 * 3600); // remove milliseconds

document.cookie="visit=" + bb + ";expires=" + ee.toGMTString();

}
setinvitexpire();
```

PHP:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_COOKIE['visit'])){ 
echo date('m/d/Y g:i A', $_COOKIE['visit']); 
echo "<br>";
} 
?>
```

I get:

```
06/26/2012 11:57 AM
```

instead of:

```
06/26/2012 18:07 AM
```

because the current time in my country is **06/25/2012 18:07 AM**

How can I resolve this and simply save the current time + 24hours in a cookie ?

EDIT:
I resolved in this way:

```
document.cookie="visit=" + <?php echo time() + (24 * 3600); ?> + ";expires=" + ExpireC.toGMTString();
```

Comment: Have you considered that possibly either the client or server's clock is set incorrectly?

Comment: You need to set the correct timezone on the server.

Comment: @Amber: that's an option, but more likely the OP is right: the server and client just have different times. Could just have the server output the time to the client and set the cookie value with that that.

Comment: @haylem: since there are no timezones that are offset by 20m from any other timezones, there is definitely a problem with one of the clocks here.

Comment: And the time will be off because of the amount of time it takes to generate the response, go through the tubes and for the page to render.

Comment: maybe my server is in another country. I can't set the timezone in my shared server.

Comment: Use the time based on UTC, not the local time.

Comment: @Dancrumb: doesn't really matter, could be both a separate timezone and a badly configured clock either side, for all we know.

Comment: I resolved, please see my edit question and let me know if it is a right approach :D

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the GMT (~ UTC) time, you have to save both the UTC time **AND** the timezone. See `getTimezoneOffset()` : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset

On a side note :

[toGMTString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toGMTString) is deprecated, you should use `toUTCString`.